# PHP nested foreach to create something like Cartesian Product

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, cartesian-product

I've ran into a problem while creating a script on PHP. I have 3 arrays `styles`, `colors` and `sizes` (this is the order). I need to combine values between them to get something like a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). 3 imbricated foreachs should help, **but** any (or even all) can be empty. How to combine them corectly?

Ex:

```
$styles = array('formal', 'dressy');
$colors = array();
$sizes = array(16, 18);
```

The result should be:

```
$res = array(
    array('style' => 'formal', 'size' => 16),
    array('style' => 'formal', 'size' => 18),
    array('style' => 'dressy', 'size' => 16),
    array('style' => 'dressy', 'size' => 18),
);
```

If `$colors` weren't empty, then between style and size should be the color. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would the output look like if there were more than one size?

Comment: Can any of the nested arrays have more than one style, size, or color?

Comment: @SLoW, added another size.

user2278120, I need 'Cartesian Product', this means that in $res it shoulb be one and only one value from each array!

Comment: @VictorStanciu, Tested the code from that anwer and it does what I need. When I found it I didn't test it.